# Enable iOS 7 camera effects in UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios7, uiimagepickercontroller

Is it possible to enable the default iOS 7 camera effects when using `UIImagePickerController`? I know that it's possible to control the flash and the image quality, but I cannot find if it's possible to add the effects when capturing an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, UIImagePickerController does not offer any of the filters that you see in the iOS 7 Camera app. You would need to build those using [Core Image](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html)'s [CIFilters](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIFilter_Class/Reference/Reference.html), or something like [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage).